# Hard Refresh in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications

Using Google Web Toolkit, I'd like to code the equivalent of a `hard refresh (control + F5)`.

I don't believe (or know) if GWT's `Window.Location` will work.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location;

Window.Location = currentPage; // I don't think it'll be hard refresh
```

Comment: Can I ask you why do you need to hard refresh? Do you have external resources, or everything is handled by GWT? Because in the last case, I don't see why you want to force reload.

Comment: @AndreaBoscolo, where I'm considering adding this hard refresh, my code re-directs the users to a generic error page. However, rather than re-direct them to a generic error page, I want to re-direct them to log in again (which the hard refresh will achieve). A user's credentials expire after 15 minutes or so. I don't know how to address the underlying problem, so adding a hard refresh is better than forcing the user to open a new browser and log in again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For reloading the current page you need to call [Window.Location.reload()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#reload%28%29) method.

> Reloads the current browser window. All GWT state will be lost.

Or you can even specify your own JSNI (below how todo), because by default [force reload is false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) :

```
  public static native void forceReload() /*-{
      $wnd.location.reload(true);
    }-*/;
```

Comment: So `GWT`'s Window.Location.reload() will not force reload? But the JSNI code will if the `true` parameter is used?

Comment: If you look at Window.Location.reload() method implementation, It doesn't use `true` as a parameter. by default it is false. Yes Native Javascript does. You can add this static method to your Utility class if you have such.

Comment: With respect, shouldn't your answer only include the JSNI code then? If `Window.Location.reload()` doesn't do a hard refresh, could you please edit your answer?

Comment: :) It already answered and no need to edit. Can you see `forceReload` this is a JSNI. If you don't know what is JSNI check this: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI

Comment: with all due respect, I thought that only your answer's JSNI `forceReload()` was correct to get a hard refresh? Using `Window.location.reload()` will not do a hard refresh, right?

Comment: you should use my `forceReload()`  if you want to reload page forcefully like Ctrl+F5. If you just want F5 use  `Window.Location.reload()`

Answer (score 5):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Methods you would need to call `window.location.reload(true)` to force the reload of the current page.

Unfortunately GWT wraps only the `window.location.reload()` via `Window.Location.reload()`, and it is up to the browser to retrieve the page from the cache or from another get. This is done to achieve the most cross-browser solution.

Never tried but you should be able to use the following.

```
public static native void reload(boolean force) /*-{
  $wnd.location.reload(force);
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

For reload gwt page, you have two options:

1) **Window.Location.reload();**

Reloads the current browser window. All GWT state will be lost.

2) **Window.Location.replace("newurl");**

Replaces the current URL with a new one. All GWT state will be lost. In the browser's history, the current URL will be replaced by the new URL.